# Student loan and kaffarah

Tags: riba, kaffarah

Salam, I’m in really desperate need for help. Basically I have a student loan which have interest I repented from it but it’s the only money I have to live. I don’t live with family and they can’t give me money much, I don’t have work and it’s difficult working with no degree, I took it out of necessary. Anyways, I also missed some days of Ramadan and had to pay a certain amount of money because fasting for 4 months ( since I can’t remember if I missed two or 1 day) it would make me quite ill, I decided to pay the money from the riba money I own. Is this sin paid off? :( please help me ...I’m hopeless .. don’t have any money to pay it off and I don’t want the sin of the missed days

Answer (score -1):

If you are thinking of taking load with interest then don't take it no matter what. But if you have already taken the load and agreed to pay ribah then you have to pay it. Not paying after agreement is also sin.